# Volume of revolution (shell and washer method)

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

The problem: Find the volume of a solid formed by y=$\sqrt{x}$ and $y=x$ around $x=6$.

I am fairly sure this is right but wanted to receive verification just for peace of mind.

The sketch of region:

[image: The region in question]

Setup (*using shell method*): $ V= 2\pi[\int_{0}^1 (6-x)(\sqrt(x)-x)dx + \int_{1}^6 (6-x)(x-\sqrt(x)dx]      $
From there, I factored out a negative from the second integrand to match the first one and then my answer came out to be approximately $$2\pi(14.35) \approx 90.14   $$  Is this correct?

On another point, I kept on trying to do the washer method but came out with a negative value for a volume which makes no sense in this context. I know it splits up into two integrals but I cannot figure out where I went wrong. Your assistance is appreciated!

Comment: I have solved this numerically by a completely independent method and find that your result is correct. FYI, I used Pappus's centroid theorem and formulated the problem in the complex plane.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should consider, as the rotating section, the bounded planar region given by $$\{(x,y): x\leq y\leq \sqrt{x}\}.$$ 
Hence the volume should be (shell method and washer method):
$$V=2\pi \int_{x=0}^1(6-x)(\sqrt{x}-x)dx=\pi\int_{y=0}^1 ((6-y^2)^2-(6-y)^2)dy=\frac{28\pi}{15}.$$

Comment: Wouldn't that only give you the volume of the region between $ y=x$ and $y=\sqrt(x) $  from y=0 to 1? What about the region from y=1 to y=6?

Comment: Usually in this kind of problem we consider the bounded region  delimited by the curves (in this case $\sqrt{x}$ and $x$). I admit that in your statement this is not clearly stated.

Comment: Take a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116386/find-the-area-of-the-region-enclosed-by-y-sqrtx-y-x-rotated-about-x-6